# Default percentage font-size on the html element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I set the default html font-size is:

```
html{
    font-size: 75%; /* 12px */
}
```

Then set body font-size like below:

```
body{
    font-size: 0.75em; /* 12px */
}
```

Now, I'm gonna set 14px for p tag so it will be look like:

```
p{
    font-size: 0.875em; /* 14px */
}
```

But when I check on the browser, it looks so small. What's wrong with my above code? Thank in advance.

Comment: well of course it looks small. That's what you are setting. What is your expected output?

Comment: @CodeGodie I want to `p` tag looks bigger than default font-size, but I dont know why it looks smaller

Comment: its smaller because you're taking a percentage from the bigger size. `em` almost works like percentage in a way, it will scale down because you're applying decimals.

Comment: @CodeGodie So how can I fix it?

Comment: if you want it bigger, then apply 1.875em to your `p` tag depending on how much bigger you want it

Answer (score 1):

em scales with font size.
So 1 em is current font size and 0.5em is half of it.
Start with 12px (75%) then apply 0.75em you are at 9px if you then apply 0.875em on the 9px you will get 8px.

This link should make things clear: http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/